# Magnetic contact circuit

Tags: current, relay, magnetics, button

Which is the best circuit for using a magnetic contact for turning on a LED strip?
I would like to turn on a strip led with 12V 7A battery, but:
 1 - if I use only the magnetic contact it will be burned (when the contact is closed the LED strip have to be off so in this way I put it to ground, is it right?) (yes this is a short circuit, I'm not using this way)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fOsofU.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

2 - if I put a resistence it works but the strip led has low power:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2foz3E5.png)</sup>

3 - if I put the resistence only for the magnetic contact, when it's closed the LED strip is ON (instead should be OFF)because the current goes the same through the LED strip (I think it has a lower resistence)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fFa5uc.png)</sup>

4 - I thought I should use a transistor between the strip led and the magnetic contact but it's not enough.. 
Should I use also a relay?

Can someone help me? Am I thinking in the right way?

Comment: You're using a battery as a constant current source?  I don't know of any that work that way.  They're all (roughly) constant voltage sources, so the traditional switch in series should work just fine if you put it between the battery and the CC supply.

Comment: "You're using a battery as a constant current source? " yes, what's the problem? I can't use a traditional switch because I want an inverse logic (switch closed = OFF and not ON).

Comment: In addiction I want to use a magnetic contact for its functionality

Comment: Please don't connect circuit 1 or 2 to a 12 V 7 Ah battery! You will burn out the wires and could start a fire.

Comment: Any time you have current flowing through a battery, you're draining it.  So it's not going to last long at all with your setup.  It'll actually last longer with the LED's ON than with them OFF.  And if it's a lead-acid battery (don't know for sure, but your description sounds like it might be), then there's a lot more than 7A available to a short circuit.  In other words, the switch may literally explode.

Comment: What's wrong with the traditional series circuit?  Battery_pos->Switch->Resistor->LED_string->Battery_neg  Constant voltage through constant resistance equals constant current; in fact, that's how a lot of CC supplies actually work.

Comment: If you can't find a magnetic switch with the opposite function, then Spehro's answer is probably the way to go.  I can't think of a simpler or more efficient circuit to reverse a switch.

Comment: Have you already selected your magnetic switch? If not, you should know that magnetic switch come in both varieties: ON=closed and ON=open.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fgH0m6.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The [MOSFET](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/PSMN4R3-30PL.pdf) switches the current to the LED strip (containing series resistors and LEDs). The top connection of the LED strip is + the bottom is -. When the reed switch is closed, the MOSFET gate is connected to the source, so it is turned 'off'.

This circuit draws about 1mA from the battery when off (through the LED and R1), so it will slowly discharge the battery. You can increase R1 to 20 or 50K if that is an issue, but too high and you can damage Q1 due to slow switching.

Edit: See buffered version that draws only 12uA in the off state. D3 should have a breakdown greater than the battery voltage but less than the rating of the 4049, so I've used a 13V zener.

Comment: I'm guessing by your description that the dashed box is the LED strip?  What's D1?

Comment: Just an LED as a reminder that the circuit is drawing current. It can be replaced with a short.

Comment: Thanks! In this way it's perfect :) .. I was trying with a similar circuit but with the LED strip between collector and ground instead in series with collector and so the transistor was becaming very hot and it doesn't work..

Comment: Am I draining the battery at any time however?

Comment: Yes, when on the strip is obviously draining the battery,and when off the 10K resistor draws a bit of current. If that's a problem, it's possible to add a CD4050 to buffer the gate. See edit above.

Comment: I'm using the first circuit with a BC547 transistor. Is it normal that the trasistor become very hot?

Comment: @Nicola If you replace the $1 100A MOSFET that I suggested with a cheap TO-92 0.1A BJT (1000x worse).. it's not going to work very well at all for any reasonable definition of "LED strip".

Comment: wow, thanks @SpehroPefhany, I had never considered these aspects.. So was I "lucky" that the BJT not be burned? (My Led strip uses 0,46A).. However now I am using a IRF2805 (I had unsoldered it somewhere) and It works perfectly!